# How to get content of BLOCK types LAYOUT_TITLE, LAYOUT_SECTION_HEADER and LAYOUT_xx in Textract

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pdf, amazon-textract

I am trying to scrape multi page pdf using textract.
Need to scrape pdf and format to json based on its sections, sub sections, tables.

while trying to UI demo with LAYOUT and Table it is exactly able to show layout title, layout section, layout text, layout footer, page number

same info can be observed in csv downloaded file from UI Demo: layout.csv file.
same in json file: analyzeDocResponse.json too but it has all (LINES, WORDS, LAYOUT_TITLE, and all layout related data), i think textract does all kind of block types in sequence.

for debugging purpose, i am using below code to print entire dictionary of block.
and also block type followed by its corresponding text.

if interested in pdf file: its SmPC of Drugs: [SmPC file](https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/wp-content/uploads/Files/SMPC/Covid19/Pfizer-BioNTech-SmPC-For-Covid-19-Vaccine.pdf)

code 1: printing each block in json format.

```
def start_textract_job(bucket, document):
    response = textract.start_document_analysis(
        DocumentLocation={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucket,
                'Name': document
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes=["LAYOUT"]  # You can adjust the FeatureTypes based on your needs
    )
    return response['JobId']


def print_blocks(job_id):
    next_token = None
    while True:
        if next_token:
            response = textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id, NextToken=next_token)
        else:
            response = textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id)

        for block in response.get('Blocks', []):
            print(json.dumps(block, indent=4))

        next_token = response.get('NextToken', None)
        if not next_token:
            break
```

it is printing similiar info as per UI Demo, block type LINES, WORDS, LAYOUT_

but if i try to print text for each block type using below code, it fails to print for LAYOUT_ related , not sure why, am i missing anything?

code 2: to print block type followed by its content.

```
def start_textract_job is same as above, LAYOUT.

def print_blocks(job_id):
    next_token = None
    while True:
        if next_token:
            response = textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id, NextToken=next_token)
        else:
            response = textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id)

        for block in response.get('Blocks', []):
            print(f"{block['BlockType']}: {block.get('Text', '')}")

        next_token = response.get('NextToken', None)
        if not next_token:
            break
```

I can see values for block type LINES, WORDS
but coming empty for LAYOUT as below, i think, it is identifying in block types but not its values.

LAYOUT_TITLE:
LAYOUT_FIGURE:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_SECTION_HEADER:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_SECTION_HEADER:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_TEXT:
LAYOUT_PAGE_NUMBER:
LAYOUT_FOOTER:

any help is highly appreicated, went thru doc and few other StackOverflow questions but couldnt find any help.
New to Tetract, sorry for noob Q?, if it is :)